# Is it possible to construct a probability distribution for a given (compact) support and its first $T$ moments?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

suppose I am looking for a probability distribution that satisfies two things:

1. the first $T$ moments are $1 > m_1 > \dots >m_T > 0$, where the $m_i$ are fixed numbers (i.e., they are part of the problem description);
2. its support is contained in $[0,1]$, and the upper boundary point of the support is a given pointe $b\in [0,1]$, for which $b > m_1 $;

does such a distribution always exist? if so, how could I construct it? many thanks for any thoughts on this!

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem

Answer (score 1):

If the second moment is about $0$ then there may be counterexamples such as with $b=1$, $m_1=0.99$ and $m_2=0.01$.  In general $E[X^2] \ge (E[X])^2$.

If the second moment is about the mean then there may be counterexamples such as with $b=1$, $m_1=0.99$ and $m_2=0.98$ as that would make $E[X^2]=1.9601>1$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha >0,\;\; \beta=1$.

Its support is $[0,1]$. With these values for the parameters its pdf is

$$f(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha-1}$$

The raw moments are

$$m_T = \int_0^1x^T\alpha x^{\alpha -1}dx = \frac {\alpha}{\alpha+T}, \;\; T=1,2,...$$

always smaller than unity (and hence smaller than the upper bound of the support), and decreasing in their order, so  $1 > m_1 > \dots >m_T > 0$.

Comment: Papadopoulus: thanks for your answer, but I did not formulate the question very well: the moments $m_i$ are fixed numbers, not just any decreasing sequence. sorry about that. any ideas on the new formulation of the problem?

Comment: If what you mean is that you have a priori an _arbitrary_ series of decreasing numbers between $1$ and $0$, and you want these numbers to represent the moments of a distribution, then, no I don't think you can find one -except if they were actually generated from the MGF of a distribution, and you are called to discover it (and hence the distribution). This falls under the category of matching _exactly_ a function with its supposed values, and it can be done only algorithmically. It has not much to do with probability -perhaps you should change tags, to draw the attention of other users here.